# How can I set `Content-Disposition : attachment` header in azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want this header to be there on every file served from azure blob storage. Their documentation says it can be set, but they don't explain how. Even the support engineers at Microsoft are not aware of this. Can someone help me this. Screenshots would be great .

I am using paperclip gem to handle the file creation with azure-sdk

Comment: Can you tell if you’re using any SDK?

Comment: i want to know if it can setup from azure rather than using sdk or programatic setup, because i recently migrated from AWS to Azure

Comment: You can use Microsoft Storage Explorer to set the content disposition property on the blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated 0707:**

If you visit the blob via its public url from browser, the default version of blob rest api is `2009-09-19`.

If you want to see the blob properties in the response, you should specify the version of blob rest api to `2019-12-12`.

Here is a test with postman, and specify the version to `2019-12-12`:

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

You can set this property via `Azure Storage Explorer`, please follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows) to download and learn how to use it.

Here is a screenshot of how to set it via `Azure Storage Explorer`(right click on the blob -> select properties, then you can set it):

[image]

**If you** don't want to download this tool, you can nav to azure portal -> the storage account -> and on the left blade, click on "Storage Explorer(preview)" -> then you can set the property:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however , can we set it for all blobs served from storage

Comment: @SandeepVattapparambil, if we do it from the tool, we can only set it one by one. You can consider using code, which may be quicker.

Comment: even after adding from here, its still not reflecting in the response header, will it take time ?

Comment: hi @SandeepVattapparambil, how do you access the blob? via code or something else?

Comment: i access the blob from brwser with its public url

Comment: @SandeepVattapparambil, it's the rest api version issue. Please refer to the update section in my answer.

Comment: can we set the rest api version of blob to 2019-12-12 globally so that all responses will have it rather than requesting for it specifically